# C# OWIN framework storing credentails

Tags: c#, security, authentication, owin

We have a hosted service which has OWIN framework as an authentication mechanism, now we have a windows service which calls this service periodically, we have stored user credentials in one of the JSON file so that it can call the service to get token and then process the request using the token however storing user credentials is a security threat.

I need to get rid of this JSON file and store credentials of the user in a safer place or do we have some other way to get token without storing credentials could you please give me an idea of how to accomplish this??

**Note**: The windows service and the IIS service are distributable services and it will be installed using user credentials so we cannot have any service account over here.

```
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder appBuilder, Func<string, string, string> authAction)
        {
            var expiry = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(40);

            var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = expiry,
                Provider = new AuthorizationProvider(authenticationAction),
                Refresh = new Refresh()
            };

            // Token Generation
            appBuilder.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
            appBuilder.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        }
```

Comment: Use Default Credentials which uses a Windows Password Server to authenticate using Windows encryption which is safe.  The Server and Client must both be using the same Password Server for Default Credentials to work.

Comment: Sorry @jdweng I didn't get you on this, I guess I didn't specify the requirements clearly, the windows service and the IIS service are distributable services and it will be installed using user credentials so we cannot have any service account kind of scenario over here.

Comment: If both machines are in the same group  Then user credentials (username/password)are the same.  S default credentials are the user login credentials.  If the user can login to both machines with the same account then you simply user the default credentials.  When a user logins to a machine on a corporate network the credentials are verified by a Password Server on the network.

Comment: @jdweng the machines will be under the same domain however the credentials are verified using active directory against the provided domain(we are using PrincipalContext), will the default credentials work ??                                                                             Also I would like to get some security architecture help could you please let me know where to post the question?

Comment: If the same user account works on both windows machine you are on the same domain and default credentials will work.  Default credentials uses the window user account of the current person who is logged in.